# In the phrase "Good afternoon" what type of word is "afternoon"?

Tags: phrases

In the phrase "Good afternoon" what type of word is 'afternoon'?

I've argued that it was a temporal pronoun, but a colleague googled the term "temporal pronoun" and came up with almost nothing, so I'm now convinced that is an incorrect description.

Is there a category that succinctly describes the temporal part of traditional greeting such as "Good morning", "Good day", "Good night"?

Comment: Where's the *pro-* from, please?

Comment: Sorry @Kris I don't know - I just called it that because it sounded sensible to me.  Are you suggesting it's just a noun and there's no more specific term?

Comment: I think *afternoon*. by itself, is a temporal noun; *good afternoon* is a phrasal exclamation.

Comment: @Kris An argument could be made that *afternoon* is deictic, as its semantic meaning is constant but what it denotes varies with time and context. So if you're looking for a fancy term to show off your grammatical chops, try *deictic noun* (but be prepared to debate it a little with anyone already familiar with deixis).

Comment: @DanBron I don't think deictic noun has anything to do with the expression at hand.

Comment: @Kris Care to counter the mini-argument I made for *afternoon* being deictic in my original comment? You don't have to, obviously, and we can drop it, but simply gainsaying my suggestion doesn't tell me much.

Comment: So the reason I was looking to categorise the "afternoon" in particular, rather than the entire phrase "good afternoon" was because someone sent me an email saying "Good afternoon" at 11:59 and I was being a pedant (Not to them, but to colleagues).  I stated that they were a little keen on their temporal pronoun.  So it's specifically the "afternoon" part that is in question, rather than "Good afternoon".

Comment: @MattFellows Ah, so you were bitten by [Muphry's Law](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muphry%27s_law)? Well, I suppose they call it a law for a reason. (No, I did not misspell *Murphy's*; follow the link.)

Comment: @DanBron Indeed...  The pedant was out pedanted ;)

Comment: The word "afternoon" is simply a noun, referring to a part of the day. No different than the word "arm" being a noun referring to a part of the body.
It's the "good" portion of this expression which holds the intrigue/mystique.
Etymologists appear to agree that the "good" part of good day, good morning, good afternoon, comes from the old expression "God......be with you"......or as we say now: Goodbye. All of these are conventional, polite expressions used when greeting or parting.

Comment: Day names are calendric, not deictic; Tuesday is still Tuesday whether it's today or not. Check out [Fillmore's Deixis lectures](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Deixis.html).

Comment: The absence of a defined endpoint to afternoon could be argued to make it diectic?  Is 7pm afternoon? What about 5? 4? etc.

Answer (score -1):

Afternoon would be considered as a common compound noun, but different periods of the day don't classify under one category of nouns, though they all seem to be common nouns.